# How to get the process ID without using a shell script as arg to OS Process Sampler - Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to obtain the id of a background process using JMeter.

I'm looking for the output of:

```
ps -ef | grep [b]ackend.js | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

I cannot use a shell script because I don't want the script to be a dependency; is there a way to execute the above command in JMeter via OS Process Sampler or another plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `-c` option of Bash shell, as per the [manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash)

> -c
>
> Read and execute commands from the first non-option argument command_string, then exit. If there are arguments after the command_string, the first argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters. The assignment to $0 sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

So:

1. Add [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Command: `/bin/bash`
   - First command parameter: `-c`
   - Second command parameter: `ps -ef | grep [b]ackend.js | awk '{ print $2 }'`

     [image: Bash Script Os Process simpler]

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more information on launching 3rd-party programs from JMeter tests.